# Regex to extract value at fixed position index

Tags: regex

I have the following string of characters:

```
73746174652C313A312C310D
                     |
                      - extract the value at this position
```

I would like to extract the value 1 (the 1 at the end of the string) using regex.

So basically a regex that acts as a charAt(index).

I need this solution for a 3rd party application that only supports regular expressions. Note that the application cannot access capture groups and does not support negative lookbehinds.

Comment: Why regex instead of charAt? `'73746174652C313A312C310D'.charAt(21)` works fine?

Comment: the system requires regex - otherwise this would be a simple task.

Comment: On what language/tool you want this regex?

Comment: I have tried to make it work in the following tool - scroll down in your browser: http://www.zytrax.com/tech/web/regex.htm#submatches

Comment: @user2652736: Use your input with this regex: `(.).{2}$` and you will get this output: `Backreferences: $1 = 1`

Comment: Still it returns a match of 10D - and not the backreference value. Close but not usable.

Comment: @user2652736 Have you looked at my answer below? It returns what you're after, with choices as to how you want to match that position

Comment: @SmokeyPHP yeah, but I can't really use those formats - as the're not a single regex. Perhaps if you tried this tool: zytrax.com/tech/web/regex.htm#submatches - it is very close to my 3rd party app.

Comment: @user2652736 The problem I see from the docs you just provided is that it has quite a poor regex engine. If it supported lookbehinds you could do something like this [`(?<=.{21}).`](http://regex101.com/r/hR0uB8)

Comment: @user2652736 `(.).{2}$` says `Backreferences: $1 = 1` - which is what you wanted? Are you looking at `first match:` ? Because you won't get what you want from there

Comment: @user2652736 Please note the regex tag summary: *Please also include a tag specifying the programming language or tool you are using.*

Comment: @user2652736 See the end of my [updated answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18056516/763371)

Comment: If there are no lookbehinds and you can only access first match, then there is no solution.

Comment: Correction: lookarounds

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C#:

```
(?<=^.{21})(.)
```

in JS:

```
/.(?=.{2}$)/
```

Comment: Yeah - a bit like the other solutions - close but: <73746174652C313A312C31>0D
First match: 73746174652C313A312C31 at position 1
Backreferences: $1 = 1 - this returns 73746174652C313A312C31 not 1

Comment: Updated, please check it.

Comment: So the system you're using doesn't support look-behind?

Comment: Well that is if the length is always the same

Answer (score 2):

The 22nd character is in capture group 1.

```
/^.{21}(.)/
```

But what system are you in that requires this instead of normal string processing?

Comment: That is close. Tried ^.{20}(.) - but the match returns 73746174652C313A312C3 - I would like it to return 1 in a single stmt.

Comment: perhaps ^.{21}(.) - if i could replace the match with backreference \1

Comment: You didn't say you couldn't access the capture groups. If you won't tell us what the system allows, we can't give you a working answer.

Answer (score 2):

You could try:

```
(?<=^.{21}).
```

It won't work in Javascript, but perhaps it will work in your app.

It means: a single character preceded `(?<= ... )` by the beginning of the string `^` plus 21 characters `.{21}` . So, in the end, it returns the 22th character.

Comment: @HamZa Only move it :-)

Answer (score 0):

Depends how you want to match it ( x distance from the beginning or  x distance from the end )

`/(.).{2}$/` Third from the end (capturing group 1)

`/^.{21}(.)/` 22nd character (capturing group 1)

```
//PHP
$str = '73746174652C313A312C310D';

$char = preg_replace('/(.).{2}$/','$1',$str); //3rd from last

preg_match('/(.).{2}$/',$str,$chars); //3rd from last
$char = $chars[1];

preg_match('/^.{21}(.)/',$str,$chars); //22nd character
$char = $chars[1];


//JS
var str = '73746174652C313A312C310D';
var ch = str.replace(/(.).{2}$/,'$1'); //3rd from last
var ch = str.match(/(.).{2}$/)[1]; //3rd from last
var ch = str.match(/^.{21}(.)/)[1]; //22nd character
```

If you're having to use the result of the `First match:` bit of your tool, run it twice:

`73746174652C313A312C310D` - `^.{21}.` = 73746174652C313A312C31

`73746174652C313A312C31` - `.$` = 1